# In Mongo what is the difference between sharding and replication?

Tags: mongodb

Replication seems to be a lot simpler than sharding, unless I am missing the benefits of what sharding is actually trying to achieve. Don't they both provide horizontal scaling?

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52632/223474)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to put this somewhere...

The most basic way to run mongo is as standalone server.

- You write a config (file or cli options)
- initiate the server using `mongod`

For this picture, I didn't include the "client". Check the next one.

[image: standalone]

- A replica set is a set of servers initialized exactly as above with a different config file.
- To link them, we connect to one of them, and initialize the replica set mode.
- They will mirror each other (in the most common configuration). This system guarantees high availability of data.

The initialization of the replica set is represented in the red border box.

[image: replica set]

- Sharding is not about replicating data, but about fragmenting data.
- Each fragment of data is called chunk and goes to a different shard. shard =  each replica set.
- "main" server, running `mongos` instead of `mongod`. This is a router for queries from the client.

[image: sharded cluster]

**Obvious**: The trade-off is a more complex architecture.
**Novelty**: configuration server (again, a different config file).

There is *much* more to add, but apart from the words the pictures hold much the same.

---

Even mongoDB recommends to study your case carefully before going sharding. Vertical scaling (vs) is probably a good idea at least once *before* horizontal scaling (hs).

vs is done upgrading hardware (cpu, ram, etc). hs is needs more computers (but could be cheap computers).

Answer (score 131):

In the context of scaling MongoDB:

- *[replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/)* creates additional copies of the data and allows for automatic failover to another node.  Replication may help with horizontal scaling of reads if you are OK to read data that potentially isn't the latest.
- *[sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction)* allows for horizontal scaling of data writes by partitioning data across multiple servers using a *shard key*.  It's important to [choose a good shard key](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key).  For example, a poor choice of shard key could lead to "hot spots" of data only being written on a single shard.

A sharded environment does add [more complexity](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction#ShardingIntroduction-ShardinginaNutshell) because MongoDB now has to manage distributing data and requests between shards -- additional configuration and routing processes are added to manage those aspects.

Replication and sharding are typically combined to created a *[sharded cluster](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Simple+Initial+Sharding+Architecture)* where each shard is supported by a replica set.

From a client application point of view you also have some control in relation to the replication/sharding interaction, in particular:

- [Read preferences](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/replication/#read-preference)
- [Write concerns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/replication/#write-concern)

Comment: "In mongodb each shard is a replica set" - this is not true. You can add individual servers as shards.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: thanks, clarified "is" as "can be".  Ideally your shard *should* be a replica set so there is some redundancy/failover.  Similarly, a replica set *should* run on multiple servers (but technically, does not have to).

Comment: I suggest removing "builds on replication" clause. It does not build on it. The two things are completely orthogonal. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: in a typical sharded MongoDB deployment you will see replication used with sharding, but the concepts are indeed orthogonal.  Thanks for the feedback .. have improved the answer.

Answer (score 74):

Consider you have a great music collection on your hard disk, you store the music in logical order based on year of release in different folders.
You are concerned that your collection will be lost if drive fails.
So you get a new disk and occasionally copy the entire collection keeping the same folder structure.

Sharding >> Keeping your music files in different folders

Replication >> Syncing your collection to other drives

Comment: very well explained.

Comment: Stackoverflow needs more answers in such a style.

Comment: I think Replication is like keeping your music file in different folders (not sharding)

Answer (score 48):

Replication is a mostly traditional master/slave setup, data is synced to backup members and if the primary fails one of them can take its place. It is a reasonably simple tool. It's primarily meant for redundancy, although you can scale reads by adding replica set members. That's a little complicated, but works very well for some apps.

Sharding sits on top of replication, usually. "Shards" in MongoDB are just replica sets with something called a "router" in front of them. Your application will connect to the router, issue queries, and it will decide which replica set (shard) to forward things on to. It's significantly more complex than a single replica set because you have the router and config servers to deal with (these keep track of what data is stored where).

If you want to scale Mongo horizontally, you'd shard. 10gen likes to call the router/config server setup auto-sharding. It's possible to do a more ghetto form of sharding where you have the app decide which DB to write to as well.

Comment: love the "More ghetto form" phrase

Answer (score 29):

## Sharding

Sharding is a technique of splitting up a large collection amongst multiple servers. When we shard, we deploy multiple `mongod` servers. And in the front, `mongos` which is a router. The application talks to this router. This router then talks to various servers, the `mongod`s. The application and the `mongos` are usually co-located on the same server. We can have multiple `mongos` services running on the same machine. It's also recommended to keep set of multiple `mongod`s (together called **replica set**), instead of one single `mongod` on each server. A replica set keeps the data in sync across several different instances so that if one of them goes down, we won't lose any data. Logically, each replica set can be seen as a **shard**. It's transparent to the application, the way `MongoDB` chooses to shard is we choose a **shard key**.

[image: MongoDB sharding]

Assume, for `student` collection we have `stdt_id` as the shard key or it could be a compound key. And the `mongos` server, it's a range based system. So based on the `stdt_id` that we send as the shard key, it'll send the request to the right `mongod` instance.

**So, what do we need to really know as a developer?**

- `insert` must include a shard key, so if it's a multi-parted shard key, we must include the entire shard key
- we've to understand what the shard key is on collection itself
- for an `update`, `remove`, `find` - if `mongos` is not given a shard key - then it's going to have to broadcast the request to all the different shards that cover the collection.
- for an `update` - if we don't specify the entire shard key, we have to make it a multi update so that it knows that it needs to broadcast it

Answer (score 18):

Whenever you're thinking about sharding or replication, you need to think in the context of writers/update operations. If you don't need to scale writes then replications, as it fairly simpler, is a good choice for you.

On the other hand, if you workload mostly updates/writes then at some point you'll hit a write bottleneck. If write request comes Mongo blocks other writes request. Those write request blocks until the first request will be done. If you want to scale this writes and want parallelize it then you need to implement sharding.

Answer (score 4):

Both replication and sharding can be used (individually or together) for horizontal scaling of a MongoDB installation.

**Sharding** is MongoDB's solution for meeting the demands of data growth. Sharding stores data records across multiple servers to provide faster throughput on read and write queries, particularly for very large data sets.
Any of the servers in the sharded cluster can respond to a read or write operation, which greatly speeds up query responses.

**Replication** is MongoDB's solution for providing stability, backup, and disaster recovery to a MongoDB installation. This process copies and synchronizes the replica data set across multiple servers. This prevents downtime if one server goes offline.

Any of the secondary servers can respond to read queries, but only the primary server will perform write operations. The results of the write operation will then be propagated out to the secondary servers.

***Scenario 1: Fault-Tolerance***
In this scenario, the user is storing billing data in a MongoDB installation. This data is mission-critical to the user's business, and needs to be available 24/7, even if a server crashes or is taken offline.

MongoDB replication is the best solution for this user. With replication, the entire data set is mirrored on multiple servers. If a server fails or is taken offline, the other servers in the cluster take over.

***Scenario 2: High Performance***
In this scenario, the user is running a social networking site which is run from a MongoDB database. As the social network grows, the MongoDB data set has grown along with it. The user is seeing query times and page loads increase beyond an acceptable point. It is critical that the user's MongoDB installation receives a major performance boost.

Setting up a sharded MongoDB cluster is the best solution for this user. The sharded cluster will break up the user's data set and store parts of it on separate secondary servers. Each secondary server can respond to read or write queries on its portion of the data, which greatly increases the installation's response time

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Atlas is a Database as a service in could. It support three major cloud providers such as Azure , AWS and GCP. In cloud environment , we usually talk about high availability and  scalability. In Atlas “clusters”, can be either a replica set or a sharded cluster.
These two  address high availability and  scalability features of our cloud environment.

In general Cluster is a group of servers used to achieve a specific task. So sharded  clusters are used to store data in across multiple machines to meet the demand of data growth. As the size of the data increases, a single machine may not be sufficient to store the data nor provide an acceptable read and write throughput. Sharded clusters supports the horizontal scalability of the underling cloud environment.

A replica set in MongoDB is a group of mongod processes that maintain the same data set. Replica sets provide redundancy and high availability, and are the basis for all production deployments.In a replica, one node is a primary node that receives all write operations. All other instances, such as secondaries, apply operations from the primary so that they have the same data set. Replica set mainly focus on the availability of data.

Please check the [documentation](http://%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)

Thank You.