# can i use MongoReplicaSetClient even for one server?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My question is dumb, so sorry.

Is it a good idea to use `MongoReplicaSetClient` instead of `MongoClient` even for one server, and then trying to expend it with time **Horizontal Scale Strategy** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replica sets are not related to horizontal scaling strategy (that would be sharding).

Replica sets are used for high availability - replicating data to other servers.  You can have one server be configured as a replica set with only one member though, of course, that does not provide you any high availability since there is nothing to fail over to if that one node fails.

Comment: replicat sets are the base of the shards?

Comment: exactly.  each shard can be a stand-alone mongod or a replica set of 1 or more nodes.  at least three nodes is common for HA but that's purely dependent on your requirements.

Comment: can you please give me the exact difference between replicaset and shard since a node can be both, i found this but not clear, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571273/in-mongo-what-is-the-difference-between-sharding-and-replication

Comment: they are independent entities. a node can be a member of a replica set.  A replica set can be a shard in a sharded cluster or not.

Comment: a shard will not contain all the  data, but the replicaset has all the database (copy) in read only mode?

Comment: replica set has N nodes - each of those nodes has the exact same set of data as the other replica set nodes.   sharded cluster splits its data across X shards - each shard has 1/X of the data on each of its replica nodes.